How to Dynamically Load Configuration Files in Angular from External Sources in a Kubernetes Environment
I'm working on an Angular application where I need to dynamically load configuration files (specifically API endpoint URLs) from external sources. The application is deployed in a Kubernetes environment, and I'm using Docker images for deployment.
Here is my current setup:
I have a placeholder for the path in the Docker image.
Different configuration files are attached as config maps for different environments in Kubernetes.
I want to dynamically load the configuration of the API endpoint so that it can change based on the environment it's deployed in. For example, the apiEndpoint might look like this in one environment:
apiEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8082/dashboard/'

Steps Taken:

Deployed the application in Kubernetes.
Attached different configuration files as config maps for different environments.

Issues:
I'm unsure how to dynamically load these configuration files in my Angular application. Specifically, I need guidance on:

Loading the configuration file at runtime.
Accessing the loaded configuration in my Angular services for backend calls.

Could someone provide a sample code or a guide to achieve this? Any help or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

Rel.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71102476/pass-environment-variable-value-to-angular-app-from-docker-file ?

For the kubernetes part, you can use envFrom or valueFrom to load variables from config map to env. Let's suppose you have deployed the config map with special-config in each kubernetes env. Then:
envFrom:
apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
   name: some-container
 spec:
   containers:
     - name: some-container
       envFrom:
       - configMapRef:
           name: special-config

or valueFrom:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: some-container
spec:
  containers:
    - name: some-container
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: special-config
              key: special.config

and for the angular part, you can see it in the question of here.
